# java Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils

Tags: java, maven, classnotfoundexception

I am able to compile my code and run it in my local (windows) machine using Eclipse. However, when I do it on my remote (ubuntu) machine, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
    at com.tools.App.main(App.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

I have added the following entry in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Can someone please help me understand what else I need to do to get this working? Thanks.

Comment: how do you launch that app on ubuntu, are you also using eclipse? What command do you use?

Comment: Hi, I am using command line like this:

        ~/Application/target/classes$ java com.tools.App

Answer (score 1):

that means the jar is available at compile time but when you are running your application this jar isn't present in classpath and so the error

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into the build path of your project and see if commons-io artifact is present there in the build path.